# Not connecting to internet under Ubuntu and LAN

Tags: networking, ubuntu

On a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 Machine which is connected to the LAN, I cannot connect to the internet and keep receiving the command: "Disconnected. You are now offline". This is a while on the same machine using Windows 10, I am connected to the internet so there should not be something wrong with my network card. I have tried this option:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

However the problem persists and I cannot connect to the internet. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Click the network applet in the indicator bar and make sure that networking is enabled. Then click on **Ethernet** to connect through the LAN. Also, click on **Edit Connections** and edit **Wired connection**, then make sure that in the **General** tab **Connect automatically ...** is enabled. Note that some of the device names may differ on your system.

Comment: You may need to update your LAN drivers in Ubuntu...